# Specflow 2022 Generate a Step Definition file - VSC BDD: All steps have been defined in this file already

Tags: c#, testing, automation, specflow

Just downloaded the latest version of VSC and Specflow (2022).  For my training course.

I've created as simple customer registration BDD script

I have the correct Nugget packages installed but I am unable to see the "Generate Step Definitions" when I right click.

I'm trying to create a step definition I keep getting the following error

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I'm confused by your question. So the steps *weren't* already defined? What were the exact steps you used to create the project?

Comment: Your correct.  They were not already defined.  I was trying to select the option that would allow me to create a step definition file from the feature file.  The current version of VSC and Specflow has a process that isn't as straight forward as the older version.  Plus my 3 year old udemy course has not been updated to reflect those changes.

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: is there any solution to fix that error?

Answer (score 5):

I had this same issue.

You have to build the solution (ctrl+shift+B) or the project (ctrl+B) first. Then try define steps again.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this helps others looking for this option. As per the [documentation](https://docs.specflow.org/projects/specflow/en/latest/visualstudio/Generating-Skeleton-Code.html) the option "Generate Step Definitions" has changed
to "Define Steps..." in Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score -1):

This is how to resolve this issue

1. Right click at the **project level**  - THIS IS MY PROJECT
2. Select **Add new item**
   3  Add SpecFlow Configuration File
3. Delete what is in the JSON file
4. Paste this code into the config file instead

   ```json
   {
     "language": {
       "feature": "en-nz"
     }
   }
   ```
5. Go into feature file and Right click a step
6. Select **Define Steps** option
7. Go through the define steps wizard
8. The step definition file will be generated
9. Add to the step definitions folder
10. To double check select step, right click and select '**go to definition**'
11. You should be taken to the step definition file step you've selected.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you have installed .NET 6.0 framework.